# Calculating triangular numbers

Tags: performance, beginner, c, programming-challenge

A triangular number is a product of three factors as follows:

$$
\text{Triangular number} = x(x + 1)(x + 2)
$$

Is there a way to make this code faster? As it is the code calculates every triangular number less than or equal to the integer given by the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {       

    int firstFactor = 0;
    int secondFactor = 1;
    int thirdFactor = 2;

    int userInput;
    int product = 0;

    printf("Enter a integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &userInput);

    if(userInput == 0) {
        printf("User input is a triangular number\n");
        return 0;
    }

    do {
        firstFactor++;
        secondFactor++;
        thirdFactor++;
        product = firstFactor * secondFactor * thirdFactor;
    } while(product < userInput);

    if(product == userInput) {
        printf("User input is a triangular number\n");
    } else {
        printf("User input is not a triangular number\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code is reasonably fast, there is not much you can do to optimize it.  Unfortunately, the algorithm is O(n^0.333).  A faster algorithm does exist, which allows you to compute the answer in \$O(1)\$ time.  Since this is a programming puzzle, I won't provide you the algorithm, but read this comment carefully for a hint.

Comment: @AJNeufeld If we are on the same page, I want to challenge the \$O(1)\$ possibility for unrestricted \$n\$ (for `int n` everything is \$O(1)\$). \$O(\log \log n)\$ seems more likely.

Comment: @vnp Challenge accepted.  Assuming I've done this right, I've created a chat-room between you & me, where we can explore this.

Comment: Point me where I'm wrong please. Your formula don't match the `nth triangular number` but `6 * nth triangular number`. [That's right](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-missing-number-in-0-6-24-60-120-336-What-is-an-explanation-to-this-sequence) ?  [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

Comment: @Calak The formula that is used in this code was given by my professor. After seeing the pages that you linked i think that you are right.

Comment: @Calak: Actually, it is 6 times the *sum* of all triangular numbers up to T(n).

Answer (score 3):

I see a couple of ways to speed this up.

Observe that at least one factor is even, and exactly one factor is a multiple of 3, so these numbers are all divisible by 6. Assuming random input, testing for that at the beginning will find the answer in one inexpensive operation in 5 out of 6 cases:

```
if (userInput % 6) {
    printf("User input is not a triangular number\n");
    return 0;
}
```

As for the rest of it, if we set n = x + 1, we get

$$T(n-1)=(n-1)(n)(n+1)=n^3-n$$

Thus, we can solve in O(1) time, though the cube root is a somewhat expensive operation:

```
#include <math.h>    /* Link with -lm in gcc */

int n;

n = (int) (ceil(cbrt(userInput)) + 0.1);
if (n * (n-1) * (n+1) == userInput)
    printf("User input is a triangular number\n");
else
    printf("User input is not a triangular number\n");
```

We add `0.1` after the `ceil` because the `double` value might be something like `6.9999999999759`, which would round to the wrong number when converted to `int`. The `(int)` cast suppresses a compiler warning about conversion from `double` to `int`.

Comment: Since my answer currently has more upvotes, I feel obliged to point out that I consider @Toby Speight’s answer more valuable, as it addresses issues of correctness, robustness, and simplicity. I say this even though the OP asked for ways to speed things up; speed is nice but correctness is *essential*.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a reasonably competent attempt.  It's very clear how it works.  I have a few observations or improvements:

- When reading input using `scanf()` (or otherwise), it's imperative to check for errors.  In this case, we just need to ensure that the return value (number of conversions made) is 1 (i.e. `scanf()` has assigned to `userInput`):

  ```
  if (scanf("%d", &userInput) != 1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "User input is not a number!\n");
      return 1;
  }
  ```
- Should we be accepting negative inputs?  I think it would be better to use `unsigned int` and to ask the user only for positive values.
- We don't really need three variables for the factors.  Since `secondFactor` is always equal to `firstFactor+1` and `thirdFactor` is always equal to `firstFactor+2`, we can replace them with those expressions:

  ```
  do {
      firstFactor++;
      product = firstFactor * (firstFactor + 1) * (firstFactor + 2);
  } while(product < userInput);
  ```

  I might re-write that as a `for` loop, since there's an increment step (`firstFactor++;`).
- Beware of arithmetic overflow - if the input is near `INT_MAX` (or `UINT_MAX` after moving to unsigned type), then `product` might exceed the limit of integer type - that's particularly bad for signed types, where overflow is Undefined Behaviour.  We might want to ensure that we don't reach that limit, either by using a wider type for `product` than `int` (if one exists - `long long int` could be the same size) or by testing product against the cube root of the limit (perhaps using `cbrt()` from `<math.h>`).
- We don't need a special test for `userInput == 0`.  If we compute `product` *before* incrementing `firstFactor`, then the first iteration of the loop will produce 0.
- We could improve the printing, by formatting the tested number as part of the output.

---

## Modified code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter an integer: ");

    unsigned int userInput;
    if (scanf("%u", &userInput) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "User input is not a number!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* avoid overflow by dividing input by one of the factors */
    for (unsigned int firstFactor = 0;  firstFactor * (firstFactor + 1) <= userInput / (firstFactor + 2);  ++firstFactor) {
        if (userInput == firstFactor * (firstFactor + 1) * (firstFactor + 2)) {
            printf("%u is a triangular number\n", userInput);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    printf("%u is not a triangular number\n", userInput);
    return 0;
}
```